# Getting biggest element in TreeSet O(1) time?

Tags: java, c++, iterator, binary-search-tree, hashset

Calling `last()` will get me the biggest element but it's O(logN) time and I know in C++ I can take advantage of the iterator and calling the `rbegin()` is constant time, can I achieve this constant time with Java's TreeSet when getting the biggest element?

example code in C++:

```
set<int> s;

s.insert(5);
s.insert(3);
s.insert(7);
... // say I inserted a total of n elements.
s.insert(0);
s.insert(9999);

cout<<*s.begin()<<endl;  //0
cout<<*s.rbegin()<<endl; //9999
```

Comment: I think you're slightly misinterpreting what it means for `rbegin()` to be "constant time". I think the documentation is implying that actually obtaining the iterator itself is constant time, but my guess is that actually *iterating* will still be logarithmic. Alternatively, it's possible to optimize getting the first/last element just by storing/updating extra pointers to the left-most and right-most elements of the underlying tree respectively. It's possible `set` authors have done so, though I don't believe the `TreeSet` authors have. That said, it is a trivial augmentation if you want.

Comment: To get the max element I just need to call `*s.rbegin()` so I don't really need to iterate. Right, I can solve it myself by tracking the max, just wondering if TreeSet author have already done it.

Comment: It's possible that the returned iterator object has overloaded the * operator, so without knowing more about its implementation, I don't think that's proof that getting the last element is actually O(1) overall. That said, it doesn't matter much, since `TreeSet` definitely isn't. Tracking largest/smallest yourself in some way is still your best option.

Comment: You can implement a augmented balance tree and maintain it on each delete and insert operation. If you have a maximum attribute in each node  changing it will only affect their ancestors so delete and insert should stay O(lg(n)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeSet does not track the extra data that would be required to provide constant-time access to the greatest element. This is quite unlikely to affect the time complexity of any algorithm that uses a TreeSet, as you'd have to perform more `last()` calls than `add()` or `remove()` calls for it to change the time complexity.

If you do perform so many `last()` calls that this matters, you could cache the `last()` result yourself and only recompute it if you've modified the set since the previous call. Alternatively, a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) might fit your use case better.

(The fact that `std::set` *does* track this data means that it has to perform extra work on operations that restructure the set, even if you don't need it.)

Comment: I have about same amount of insert/erase random element and getting max operations and PriorityQueue is bad for erase operation. TreeSet is much better, it seems I'll have to keep track of max by myself if I really want O(1) for it. Thx!